# How to display display all bar in ggplot

Tags: r

Display 10 bars based on score.

I want to display 10 bars based on individual_score. Since CH Gayle and AB de Villiers is repeated twice I am only getting 8 bars. But I want to show 10 bars based on score in descending order.

```
batsman        individual_score   
CH Gayle    175
BB McCullum 158
AB de Villiers  133
RR Pant 130
AB de Villiers  129
CH Gayle    128
M Vijay 127
DA Warner   126
V Sehwag    122
SR Watson   121
```

I tried reorder for descending order but it does not work. I also tried `fill = score` and `batsman` to get 10 bars.

```
highest_individual_score <- innings %>%
group_by(match_id,batsman) %>%
summarize(individual_score = sum(batsman_runs)) %>%
arrange(desc(individual_score)) %>%
ungroup() %>%
top_n(10, individual_score) %>%
ggplot(aes(x= batsman, y = individual_score,fill = batsman)) +
geom_bar(stat= "identity", show.legend = FALSE) +
theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90)) +
labs(x = "Batsman", y = "Individual Score", title ="Top 10 highest 
individual scorer")
```

The above code gives me only 8 bars in alphabetical order. How do I make it display 10 bars?

Comment: Not directly related to the question but I just wanted to let you know about geom_col() which is a wrapper for geom_bar(stat = 'identity), using it can save you some typing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What if you tried something like this? With your code, `ggplot2` is grouping them together because the x-axis is `batsman`, and it's taking you literally on that. But what if you made the x-axis some unique thing, unrelated to either `batsman` or `individual_score`?

I did this below by giving each row an arbitrary unique ID. I used `row_number()` so they just go naturally in order. I then turned them into a factor (rather than leaving them as numeric) so that it works nicely with the scale.

```r
library(tidyverse)

highest_individual_score <- innings %>%
  group_by(match_id, batsman) %>%
  summarize(individual_score = sum(batsman_runs)) %>%
  arrange(desc(individual_score)) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  top_n(10, individual_score) %>% 
  mutate(id = as.factor(row_number()))
```

Then I made minor changes to your `ggplot2` code itself:

```r
highest_individual_score %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = id, y = individual_score, fill = batsman))+
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", show.legend = FALSE)+
  scale_x_discrete(
    labels = highest_individual_score$batsman,
    name = "Batsman"
  ) +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90))+
  labs(y = "Individual Score", title ="Top 10 highest 
       individual scorer")
```

Essentially, the x-axis is now the unique ID, and so it treats each record separately. But then you have to relabel the axis with your batsmen, which I did using the `labels` argument of `scale_x_discrete()`. Make sense?

Comment: Yes thank you. It makes sense.One question though. Do we have to run ggplot separately. I tried to pipe it after mutate it gives me error but running separately like above works fine.

Comment: It's because my "labels" argument refers to "highest_individual_score$batsman," but "highest_individual_score" only exists because of the intermediate step. There might be ways around that.

Answer (score 0):

The following is a hack but it works.
The trick is to paste a blank `" "` at the end of the duplicated `batsman`. Then convert to `factor`. Like this there will be all different values but the blank doesn't show up.

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

df1 %>%
  mutate(batsman = as.character(batsman),
         batsman = ifelse(duplicated(batsman), paste0(batsman, " "), batsman),
         batsman = factor(batsman)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x= batsman, y = individual_score,fill = batsman)) +
  geom_bar(stat= "identity", show.legend = FALSE) +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90)) +
  labs(x = "Batsman", 
       y = "Individual Score", 
       title ="Top 10 highest individual scorer")
```

[image]

**Data.**

```
df1 <- read.table(text = "
batsman        individual_score   
'CH Gayle'    175
'BB McCullum' 158
'AB de Villiers'  133
'RR Pant' 130
'AB de Villiers'  129
'CH Gayle'    128
'M Vijay' 127
'DA Warner'   126
'V Sehwag'    122
'SR Watson'   121
", header = TRUE)
```

Comment: This one works as well. Thank you for providing informative hack.